# How to replace amp of electric guitar with IPad

Tags: electric-guitar, amplifiers

I just wanna start learning the electric guitar (EG) as my first musical instrument and I have no knowledge about music. As I understood, I should buy an amplifier to play EG. I am wondering if it is possible to replace the amplifier with software, an app on iPad, and buy a bit more expensive guitar? If it is possible, I would be thankful if someone can explain how to do this.

**Note:** I have an amplifier to listen to music, "Pyle PT1100 Hybrid Amplifier". But, I don't know if it can be used for playing guitar or not. If it works, I would be thankful to know about it.

Comment: It's possible but doesn't make much sense IMO, because you'll only save maybe $40 compared to an amp+fx modeler like Zoom G1 Four or Mooer GE-100. And depending on things I cannot list, playing through the iPad can have an annoying latency. The saved pennies won't make any difference to how good a guitar you'll be able to buy.

Comment: If you have access to a PC, then search for ASIO in the search bar, there is a lot of information about setting up a PC to act as an amp simulator to at least test the process for almost no money. https://music.stackexchange.com/search?q=ASIO

Comment: @Yorik you still need an audio interface to connect the guitar to the PC

Comment: @ojs no, you just need line in, an 1/4-1/8 adapter, and free software. Not ideal, but it gets your foot in the door and then you can target equipment upgrades, such as a purpose-built audio adapter.

Comment: @Yorik just to check if we’re on the same page, are you aware what input impedance is?

Comment: @ojs absolutely.

Comment: @Yorik then you probably know why it’s a problem. But please go ahead and write a full answer.

Comment: @Yorik Do you have a Youtube link showing what kind of results can be achieved the way you suggest? I do not believe that onboard PC audio + free software could possibly make any kind of sense for learning electric guitar, compared to buying a $100 practice amp or modeler, with proper guitar inputs, effects and everything.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica click on the search link I provided. This whole thread is a duplicate of very many of them, and "yes" it works just fine, has decent sound quality, can have decent latency and is a virtually free introduction to the workflow. I have made that clear now for the 3rd time. see, for example "not ideal" "foot in the door" "test the process"

Comment: @Yorik the problem is that we know how electric signals work, what ASIO is and unless you have direct reference to something different, that the "not ideal" is probably same as "worse than just playing the guitar without an amp"

Comment: @ojs except you are wrong (shrug) don't know how to put it any clearer. All the direct references are there in the search results. All the discussion of high-Z impedance mismatch on the line in not harming your equipment (it won't). The free software recommendations are there, it all just works.

Comment: @Yorik all you really need to do is explain how you believe things work or provide an actual link. Also, nobody expect you thinks the impedance mismatch damages equipment. It just makes the guitar sound bad enough to be not really usable.

Comment: @ojs again, I am not going to do that, because this is a duplicate. I was going to flag for close, but then thought I would be helpful to the OP to post the links to very many pages of discussion, which again, includes software recommendations, discussion of impedance mismatch, ASIO for low latency access to hardware, ground loops. Often times, the lack of the proper words for a targeted search is really what the OP needs.

Answer (score 2):

The speakers in an iPad are remarkable for their size, but not really capable of dealing with an electric guitar! And there's no easy way of getting the guitar signal into an iPad.  It CAN be done, but remember this is Apple.  The adapter won't be cheap!

Initially, you just want a basic amplifier and speaker.  Google for 'practice amp'.  Get one with a headphone socket.  The neighbours don't need to hear the horrible noises a beginner guitarist makes!   Have fun!

Comment: IK iRig2 HD is 79€ at Thomann https://www.thomann.de/intl/ik_multimedia_irig_hd_2.htm Not bad, but Zoom G1 Four is only 77€ https://www.thomann.de/intl/zoom_g1_four_multi_effect_pedal.htm and that's a standalone device which has lots of uses even with real amps.

Comment: The expensive part is the Lightning to USB cable that comes bundled with iRig HD. The new iPads with USB-C don’t have that problem

Comment: There are even tiny practice amplifiers with no speaker at all, just a headphone output, like the [Vox AmPlug 2 series](https://voxamps.com/product/amplug-2/).

Comment: LOL, Vox Amplug 2 AC30 is 36 € at Thomann. That has to be one of the cheapest and easiest ways to get an electric guitar sound. It needs batteries though.

Answer (score 1):

With iPad is possible, but not free. For decent guitar input you need an audio interface with instrument level input, and if your iPad doesn't have USB-C and the interface doesn't come with Lightning cable, you need the misleadingly named "lightning camera adapter" that is actually a generic Lightning to USB2 adapter.

You also need an amp modeling app, which may be bundled with the interface or bought separately. The free versions that come bundled with audio interfaces are typically limited to few amp models and effects and charge extra for larger selection. On the other hand, because iPad has a lot more processing power than the tiny processors in multi effects and entry level modeling amps, the modeling can be better.

Finally, you need wired speakers or headphones. Bluetooth, AirPlay and others have too much latency to be useful and the built in speaker doesn't really cut it. iOS itself has well designed audio system and can have latency around 10 milliseconds, similar to standing three meters away from the speaker.

That being said, I have iPad, iRig HD, AmpliTube and BiasFX and in my opinion it can sound convincing and playing with effects can be fun for a while, but I have found that a small practice amp is more fun to play.